# Error al poner la url de mi botón: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s)

Tags: python, django, template, views

Hola tengo una duda quiero poner un botón en una de mis plantillas pero me genera error, me manda esto:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'documentacion_agregar' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['clientes/(?P<cliente_id>[0-9]+)/documentos/(?P[0-9]+)/\Z']

Éste es el botón:

`<a href="{% url 'documentacion:documentacion_agregar' cliente.id %}" class="btn-blue">Agregar</a>`

De acuerdo a mi url:

```
app_name='documentacion'

urlpatterns = [path('clientes/<int:cliente_id>/documentos/<int:pk>/',DocumentoCreateView, name='documentacion_agregar')]
```

si tecleo por ejemplo clientes/1/documentos/1/ puedo ver el formulario para guardar mis registros y cuando doy click en guardar me redirige a 'clientes:clientes_detalle', lo cual está bien

```
def DocumentoCreateView(request,cliente_id,pk):
   cliente = get_object_or_404(Cliente, pk=cliente_id)
   form = DocumentacionForm(request.POST)
   if request.method=='POST':
       if form.is_valid():
           documento=form.save(commit=False)
           documento.cliente=cliente
           documento.save()
           return redirect('clientes:clientes_detalle',cliente_id=cliente_id, pk=pk)
       else:
           form=DocumentacionForm()
   return render(request, "documentacion-agregar.html", {'form': form})
```

En mi base de datos veo que se guarda bien el registro de lo que quiero(que es guardar varios documentos para un cliente en específico).

El template (donde se genera el error a causa del botón), muestra el detalle de un cliente a modo de detailview y un listado de los documentos que se agregaron por cliente; si quito el botón, despliega bien la información que quiero mostrar en mi template.

¿Tienen idea de por qué me está enviando ese error con el botón? Algo me comentaron sobre los parámetros, de la cantidad que estaba mandando en mi view contra lo que tengo en mi botón, pero no entiendo bien a qué se referían

Comment: No se de django, pero la regex mencionada al final del error (?P[0-9]+)/\Z']) no está bien escrita. ?P debe estar seguido por el nombre del grupo entre < y >. Si la regex es tuya, entonces probablemente corregirla solucione el problema. Si no es así, no tengo idea.